# How to declare a new variable inside a steps.sh script in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In my groovy class I have step that goes:

```
def mergedBranch = steps.sh label:"Get the latest merged branch", script: """
            declare branch
            for branch in ${all_merged_branches}; 
            do
                merged_branch=$branch;
                echo $merged_branch
                break;
            done
      """, returnStdout: true
```

However, every time I run this on the pipeline, I get an error saying :

```
No such property: branch for class: <classname>
```

If I change the script to use triple single quotes, this error does not surface but I cannot use Groovy's string interpolation which only happens within a double quoted string. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all variables are evaluated by jenkins when they're in double quotes. If don't have all your variables defined in the environment, you should simply escape the branch and merged_branch variables, i.e. `\$branch` and '\$merged_branch`

if `all_merged_branches` exists in the environment variables, you can simply rewrite the step as

```
def mergedBranch = steps.sh label:"Get the latest merged branch", script: '''
            declare branch
            for branch in ${all_merged_branches}; 
            do
                merged_branch=$branch;
                echo $merged_branch
                break;
            done
      ''', returnStdout: true
```